# What is generally more secure? FreeNX or VNC?

Tags: security, vnc, freenx

[FreeNX](http://nomachine.com/) or [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/), which is generally more secure? I am just wondering since both give encryption.

I know FreeNX generally uses SSH which is very secure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about straight out of the box VNC, it does not provide any encryption (UltraVNC does however, and RealVNC does to, for the commercial package).

FreeNX is used over `ssh` so, it's secure by default I'd say, but you can also tunnel VNC through ssh.